# NSFetchRequest when a call returns multiple collections

Tags: core-data, restkit, nsfetchrequest, restkit-0.20

I am trying to set up RestKit to delete orphaned objects that don't exist on the server but still exist in the local cache, using `NSFetchRequest`s as described in the documentation for [`RKManagedObjectRequestOperation`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html).

If I have a call that returns multiple collections of different object types, each of which are mapped using keys, is RestKit smart enough to deal with this?  Or will it only work on calls that return objects of a single type?  For example:

URL: `/users?accessToken=someToken`

Response:

```
{
    users: [],
    collection1: [],
    collection2: [],
    collection3: []
}
```

The type of object stored in each collection is a different Entity in my data model.  How can I write an NSFetchRequest that will allow me to delete objects from the local cache that are no longer in `collection1`, `collection2`, or `collection3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as smart as you make it, but, as you can see from the docs / block signature, you need to have some information in the URL (or in the previously mapped contents in the data store) which allows you to decide what to do.

If all of your information is in the JSON response body them using a fetch request block may not work well for you and you may need to execute your own fetch and deletion based instead on the mapping result (which would run after the context was saved instead of before).

Comment: My question may not have been clear.  I'll elaborate.

Comment: Also, I did end up writing my own cache cleanup based on the contents of the `mappingResult`, but I wanted to see if it was possible to do what I wanted within the accepted RestKit paradigms.

Comment: The question is: For the request `/users...`, do you always get collection1/2/3 back, or some other arbitrary collections? Can you always return a fetch which includes all of those collections (and are they of the same entity)? RestKit offers this deletion feature, but it  is limited in a number of ways...

Comment: They are not of the same Entity.  I believe that would preclude me from using this feature?

Comment: Yes, a fetch request is specific to an entity type and RestKit will only run one fetch request block for a matching path.